# How can I find actual volume of the sound Chrome makes from pulseaudio on command line

Tags: sound, google-chrome, pulseaudio

I'm on Ubuntu 18.04 and I'm trying to find whether Chrome is playing something with sound. I'm using `pacmd list-sink-inputs` for that. When I play something with sound on Chrome (Youtube), here are the volume levels I get from `list-sink-inputs`:

```
    flags: START_CORKED 
    state: RUNNING
    sink: 15 <alsa_output.pci-0000_00_1b.0.analog-stereo>
    volume: front-left: 65536 / 100% / 0,00 dB,   front-right: 65536 / 100% / 0,00 dB
            balance 0,00
    muted: no
    current latency: 53,51 ms
    requested latency: 23,22 ms
```

when I change the volume of the Youtube video, these dB values and the percentage does not change

This works just fine on Firefox, as in, I can see the difference on the output when I change the video's volume. I want it to work on Chrome too. How do I find the actual volume levels of Chrome client?

Answer (score 0):

```
parec --raw --channels=1 --latency=2 2>/dev/null | od -N2 -td2 | head -n1 | cut -d' ' -f2- | tr -d ' '
```

Answered [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5168439/3016570).